# Layer data source changing spontaneously

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have a project in QGIS 3.22 configured as a stand alone project in QField.
I have manually changed the data source of several layers.
I have saved the project, closed it and opened it again and the data source changes have been saved. However, intermittently when working on the project, the layer data source is now changing without my (user) intervention.
I have multiple QField Projects with exactly the same layer structure. It seems the layers spontaneously change to either (1) the last opened project, or (2) the location of the template on which the project was originally based.
Has anyone else come across this issue and knows what may be causing it to happen?